Is there a way to turn off code coverage entirely in SonarQube?
Version: SonarQube: Community Edition v10.6 (92116)
I am familiar with the property sonar.coverage.exclusions for selectively turning off code coverage for certain files or folders.
Is there some other means to turn off code coverage entirely for some SonarQube project?
